# What is the IP Address to start red 5 Media Server in Browser?

Tags: red5

I have installed the red 5 media server on my Ubuntu pc using this link 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-red5-on-ubuntu-12-10
I want to test it in browser. I already tested http://localhost:5080 but it failed to load . So what should i do to test it ?

Answer (score 0):

Red5 automatically, by default, binds to IP [0.0.0.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0) which means all the IPv4 addresses on the machine. So if you ran it on your local computer, you could connect to "http://localhost:5080/" or "http://192.168.1.2:5080/" (assuming your local network IP is 192.168.1.2). When running Red5 on a remote server such as your digitalocean instance, you'll need to know its public IP address or FQDN and try to connect to it; if for instance it is "abhikumar.digitalocean.com", you'd connect like so "http://abhikumar.digitalocean.com:5080/". One other caveat is to make sure that the server instance has port 5080 open.

If you have trouble locating your IP or FQDN, look in your red5.log for any line containing "5080" or "1935".